# Bash script order mixup in large redirect of output

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a script which runs a database query and redirects the result to a csv file and after using sftp to upload it, the file is removed like this:

```
FileName=` echo "report_$StartDate:$StopDate.csv" | sed 's/\ /_/g'`

$DatabaseCommand "$Query" -f CSV | sed 's/"//g' > "$ReportDir/$FileName"

expect<<EOD
set timeout 3600
spawn sftp $USER@$HOST
expect "password:"
send "$PASSWORD\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "put $ReportDir/$FileName\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "bye\r"
EOD

rm -rf $ReportDir/$FileName
```

I know tha last line should be changed to `rm -f`, but I'm wondering is there any way that bash could mix up in the FileName line and be able to run the following command instead:

```
rm -rf $ReportDir/
```

Comment: `FileName` turns out to be empty, or starts with spaces so because of your lack of quoting, gets split up?

Comment: @muru I've run this many times without any problem but I want to make sure it is safe and not able to remove anything.

Comment: What happens the one time you do have a problem and  `FileName` becomes something like `report_*:*.csv` and you end up deleting all those files in the directory?

Comment: @muru It'd delete all files starting with report_.
But is there a way the script can somehow skip **FileName** (error or anything) and run **rm -rf $ReportDir/**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a command like that, you may want to guard against the variables being empty, regardless of how that could happen:

```
$ cat foo.sh
#!/bin/bash
ReportDir=/somepath
FileNam=$(echo ...) # oops, a typo
# ... 
rm -rf -- "${ReportDir:?}/${FileName:?}"

$ bash -x foo.sh
+ ReportDir=/somepath
++ echo ...
+ FileNam=...
foo.sh: line 5: FileName: parameter null or not set
```

The `${parameter:?message}` expansion exits with an error if `parameter` is empty or unset. The default message is usually just fine, so I didn't give one in the code above.

Alternatively, just check manually, but this is verbose and still prone to typos:

```
if [ -z "$FileName" ] ; then
    echo "FileName is empty!" >&2
    exit 1
fi
rm -rf -- "$ReportDir/$FileName"
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `StartDate`, `StopDate` and `ReportDir` are not set in the script you have shown us, I'm going to assume this is not the entire script. So:

```
$ cat foo.sh
ReportDir=foo
# commands from what you have shown, omitting `expect` and db command
FileName=` echo "report_$StartDate:$StopDate.csv" | sed 's/\ /_/g'`

rm -rf $ReportDir/$FileName
$ bash -ux foo.sh
+ ReportDir=foo
foo.sh: line 2: StartDate: unbound variable
++ sed 's/\ /_/g'
+ FileName=
+ rm -rf foo/
```

Clearly it expanded `FileName` to nothing and ran `rm -rf foo/`.

Comment: well, of course that only happens if you explicitly `set -u`, otherwise `FileName` would contain at least `report_:`

Comment: @ilkkachu or if `PATH` was broken in a way that left `rm` available but not `sed`

Answer (score -1):

Consider using [sshpass](https://gist.github.com/arunoda/7790979) instead.

> SSHPass is a tiny utility, which allows you to provide the ssh password without using the prompt. This will very helpful for scripting. SSHPass is not good to use in multi-user environment. If you use SSHPass on your development machine, it don't do anything evil.

Comment: That's one option, but not really what the question here is about, no?